# How I can retrieve the length of a part of json object using PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have retrieved a PHP variable session that contains a JSON object. The JSON object is the following:

```js
var jsonObject = {
    "menu":{
        "intro":{
            "intosub":"sub_1"
        },
        "vis":{
            "visub":"sub_2"
        }
    }
};
```

How can I know the length of a part of this JSON object? That is, I want to know how much elements that contain the key `Intro` and the same with key `vis`.

I have reviewed some post about this issue, and I found that I have to change the structure of JSON object, but this is not possible. Is there any other way in order to do this?

Comment: Why is this not possible? You don't necessary need to alter the original json string, so why not just json_decode it and work with it like it's an array?

Answer (score 1):

First,  parse json to php associative array, use json_decode(your_var, true) . You will get a multidimensional array. Then use php  count function on desired subarray